# SQL Server - Get a count even if there are no results corresponding table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query below returns problems created for a developer in last 12 months. The query below works fine, but I wanted this to return 0 when there is no match.

```
SELECT 
   count(1) as count,
   MONTH(pro.[DATE_CREATED]) AS MONTHNAME, 
   YEAR(pro.[DATE_CREATED]) AS YEARNAME ,
   problemStatus.TypeName
FROM    
   [TestDB].[dbo].PROBLEMS AS pro 
LEFT JOIN 
   [TestDB].[dbo].PROBLEMSTATUS AS problemStatus ON problemStatus.ID = pro.ID_STATUS 
LEFT JOIN 
   [TestDB].[dbo].CUSTOMER AS cust ON pro.ID = cust.ID 
WHERE 
   pro.ID = 1010101010
   AND pro.[DATE_CREATED] >= DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp) 
GROUP BY 
   MONTH(pro.[DATE_CREATED]), 
   YEAR(pro.[DATE_CREATED]), 
   problemStatus.type
ORDER BY 
   MONTH(pro.[DATE_CREATED]) DESC
```

Right now the query returns,

```
Count   Month   Year    Status
1   12  2013    Fixed
1   11  2013    Fixed
1   9   2013    Fixed
1   8   2013    Fixed
1   2   2014    Fixed
1   1   2014    Opened
1   1   2014    Fixed
```

I want this to return

```
Count   Month   Year    Status
1   12  2013    Fixed
0   12  2013    Opened
1   11  2013    Fixed
0   11  2013    Opened
1   9   2013    Fixed
0   9   2013    Opened
1   8   2013    Fixed
0   8   2013    Opened
1   2   2014    Fixed
0   2   2014    Opened
1   1   2014    Opened
1   1   2014    Fixed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have data in the table for all months, but just not for that `ID`, then try this:

```
SELECT sum(case when pro.ID = 1010101010 then 1 else 0 end) as count,
       MONTH(pro.[DATE_CREATED]) AS MONTHNAME, 
       YEAR(pro.[DATE_CREATED]) AS YEARNAME ,
       coalesce(max(case when pro.ID = 1010101010 then problemStatus.TypeName end), 'Opened') as problemStatus
FROM    [TestDB].[dbo].PROBLEMS AS pro 
left JOIN [TestDB].[dbo].PROBLEMSTATUS AS problemStatus 
ON problemStatus.ID = pro.ID_STATUS 
left  JOIN [TestDB].[dbo].CUSTOMER AS cust 
ON  pro.ID = cust.ID 
WHERE pro.[DATE_CREATED] >= DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp) 
GROUP BY MONTH(pro.[DATE_CREATED]), YEAR(pro.[DATE_CREATED]) , problemStatus.type
ORDER BY MONTH(pro.[DATE_CREATED]) DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am getting zero as count for every row.

Comment: What if there is no data for a month in the table? Any idea?
The query you gave works fine, but not when data is missing for a month.

Comment: @CoolArchTek . . . Post another question.  If you have no data for the month, the solution is more cumbersome.